# Shape Mismatch with keras multi_gpu_model, but runs fine on single GPU

Tags: keras, gpu, shapes, mismatch

My architecture is a standard seq-to-seq encoder decoder, using a keras generator so I don't have to load the TD into memory all at once. This runs perfectly in the same virtual environment where I get the error (that is, with tensorflow-gpu) if I merely change the compile and fit calls to self.model, which is to say that everything runs fine on a single GPU. But with multiple GPUs, some part of this is being flattened or recombined incorrectly resulting in a shape mismatch. Here is the error:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

----EDIT---- I was able to reproduce this error pretty trivially using the following code in a single file, with the latest version of keras+tensorflow-gpu+cuda9.2:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model, Sequence
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed, Embedding
from keras.models import Model

BATCH_SIZE = 4

class trivial_Sequence(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x = np.zeros((batch_size*4, 64))
        self.y = np.zeros((batch_size*4, 64, 1))
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x)/float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size:(idx+1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size:(idx+1)*self.batch_size]

        return batch_x, batch_y


def error_train():

    #instantiate components

    td = trivial_Sequence(None, None, BATCH_SIZE)
    input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')
    emb = Embedding(output_dim=10, input_dim = 64, input_length=None)
    encode = LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, return_state = True)
    project_up = Dense(units=20, activation='softmax')

    #build network

    temp = emb(input)
    temp, _, _ = encode(temp)
    output = TimeDistributed(project_up)(temp)

    model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = output)
    parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)

    parallel_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                       metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

    parallel_model.fit_generator(td, epochs=1, verbose=1)


#run it

error_train()
```

Comment: Is your generator a `Sequence` or just a python generator? If it's a regular generator, I suggest you change it to sequence. If you're using `stateful=True` somewhere, I think it will not be safe even if you succed (not sure, though).

Comment: it is a custom Sequence. I am not using stateful=True anywhere.

Comment: In your code I don't see the line that set the tensorflow device to `cpu`.

Comment: Which parts of this should be inside that "with tf.device cpu" block? The example in the Keras documentation only includes the model = Model( .. ) line. I made that change just now, and had the same error. I appreciate your time though.